# Setup custom domain on GithubPages with QHoster?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, nameserver, dns-hosting, github

I've registered a domain with qhoster.com (foo.com) and I want to link it to my GitHubPages webpage. I've followed [the GithubPages guide about this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages) and I don’t manage to make it work.

When I go to the domain management page of qhoster I find two relevant configuration pages:

a) Nameservers. They are configured by default like this:

```
Nameserver 1: [ ns1.qhoster.net ]
Nameserver 2: [ ns2.qhoster.net ]
Nameserver 3: [ ns3.qhoster.net ]
Nameserver 4: [ ns4.qhoster.net ]
```

b) DNS Management: the default values are as follows:

```
Host Name     | Record Type          | Address                         | Priority
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[           ] | [ A (Address)      ] | [ 107.161.23.204              ] |  N/A
[           ] | [ A (Address)      ] | [ 192.161.187.200             ] |  N/A
[           ] | [ A (Address)      ] | [ 209.141.38.71               ] |  N/A
[ www       ] | [ CNAME (Alias)    ] | [ parking.namesilo.com        ] |  N/A
[           ] | [                  ] | [                             ] | [    ]
```

I don't really understand where do those IP addresses come from, but my hope was that they would disappear or they wouldn't matter when I set up the domain to simply be a redirection to http://mygithubusername.github.io/.

Possible values for `Record Type` field (combobox) are:

- A (Address)
- List item
- AAAA (Address)
- MXE (Mail Easy)
- MX (Mail)
- CNAME (Alias)
- SPF (txt)
- URL Redirect
- URL Frame
- List item

When I choose “URL Redirect” or “URL Frame”, it only lets me add two possible values in the `Host Name` field: `http` or `https` (leaving it empty is not valid).

So I’ve tried putting filling the row like this:

```
[ http    ] | [ URL Redirect  ] | [ http://mygithubusername.github.io ] | [      ]
```

For setting up GithubPages I created a repo called “https://github.com/mygithubusername/mygithubusername.github.io” and from its settings, I fill the “Custom domain” section with `foo.com`, and I don’t check the “Enforce HTTPS option”.

The result of this is that when I direct my browser to `http://mygithubusername.github.io/` or `foo.com` it wrongly redirects me to `http//mygithubusername.github.io/`, which obviously doesn’t work.

What's the secret sauce here? Here are the responses from nslookup:

```
$ nslookup mygithubusername.github.io
Server:     192.168.43.1
Address:    192.168.43.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mygithubusername.github.io
Address: 185.199.109.153
Name:   mygithubusername.github.io
Address: 185.199.111.153
Name:   mygithubusername.github.io
Address: 185.199.110.153
Name:   mygithubusername.github.io
Address: 185.199.108.153

$ nslookup foo.com
Server:     192.168.43.1
Address:    192.168.43.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   foo.com
Address: 192.161.187.200
Name:   foo.com
Address: 209.141.38.71
Name:   foo.com
Address: 107.161.23.204
```

The only thing good that I see above is that the first address (not the "non-authoritative" ones) matches!